# Command "from sklearn.model_selection import something" runs with a mistake. What should i do?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

When I try to run my code I have an error:

> ImportError: No module named model_selection

I have my sklearn v.17 installed together with Anaconda. This occurs only if I write "model_selection" after **sklearn**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import something
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is actually in your question.

The module **model_selection** has only been introduced in the version `0.18` of `sklearn`. It does not exist in the version `0.17`.

Look at [the history here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html).

To get the module you thus need to update `sklearn`.
As you use Anconda do (in a terminal):

```
 conda update scikit-learn
```

Comment: Oh, yes i failed this way to update, because i get an error failed to create process. Though i wrote path in advanced settings for anacondas folder.

Comment: I don't get it sorry. When running `conda update scikit-learn` you get an error ?

Comment: Yes i any case - when i type it in standard terminal or in conda's terminal.

Comment: conda's terminal ? What's that ? Can you show me what you tried and the error obtained ?

Comment: Yes you can see my post below

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @MMF's answer, try the following if you want to continue using `sklearn` version `0.17`:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

Answer (score 0):

I reinstal Anaconda in the default folder and this trouble disappeared.